# Inserting new list items into SQL

Tags: 2013, splistitem, sql-server

When I add new item into the list, I have to insert the items into the SQL database. How can I do it? Any clue is good for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the head here, but can`t this be done if you [add a database as a Data Source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/sharepoint-designer-help/add-a-database-as-a-data-source-HA010100908.aspx#BM6) and set the Create All Operations on Table in BDC to work with the Database?

See also [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4sRTG4aGJL8) tutorial.

EDIT:

[Here](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2010/archive/2011/05/04/sharepoint-2010-cookbook-how-to-create-external-list-including-database-from-sharepoint-designer-2010.aspx) is another tutorial explaining in detail how to connect to a Database. It should be pretty straightforward with this.

Comment: I followed the video. I created Datasource but how can I insert list items into this datasource?

Comment: It is in the video. The author creates a new list, and manipulates the data in it. I've edited my answer with another tutorial wich should help you.

Comment: It worked. Can you tell me how can I modify the new form for this list. I can't create a dropdownlist for a field.

Comment: I think that this is a new question. But, you can create a new Page and then add the List to it. From there you can manipulate the List as you want through "Modify View" List option. And if you are asking how to add a dropdown option, this is set when you initially create the List, or edited with the "List Settings" option.

Comment: I will explain it in the new question.Because it's not what I want. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a 3rd party tool called BDLC which I have used in the past.  Very easy to set up and configure and basically allows you to create either a read-only or write-back synchronised list and database table.

Comment: It looks good too. I'll try it with another list. Thanks.